# A Markov algorithm that does unary multiplication

Tags: turing-machines, strings, multiplication, term-rewriting

I am learning Markov algorithms and came across the paper [*Markov Algorithm*](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ecarton/Enseignement/Complexite/ENS/Redaction/2007-2008/yuanmi.chen.pdf) by CHEN Yuanmi. I am trying to understand the following example (well, any of the examples in the paper).

> Example 3: Multiplication. MA3 = $\{\Sigma, P, P_0\}$
>
> - $\Sigma = \{a, A, B, C, \#\}$
> - Productions in $P$:
>   $p_1: Ba \to aB$
>   $p_2: Aa \to aBA$
>   $p_3: a \to \epsilon $
>   $p_4: a\#\to \#A $
>   $p_5: \#a \to \#$
>   $p_6: \# \to \epsilon$
>   $p_7: B \to a$
>   $p_8: \epsilon \to \cdot \epsilon$
> - $ P_0 = \{p_8\}$
>
> Remark: Given the input in form of "$\underbrace{aa...a}_x\#\underbrace{aa...a}_{y}$", the algorithm will halt with the output in the form of "$\underbrace{aa...a}_{x \times y}$".

My question is about the above example. I understand the rules should be applied in linear order. So given an input of "$aaa\#aaa$", the first rule to match would be $p_3$, which says to replace `a` with the empty character. So the string will be consumed down to a single `#`, which is then also replaced with an empty character ($p_6$), then the machine halts with no output($p_8$). How does this achieve multiplication? What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have demonstrated that example on multiplication cannot be correct.

Well, there is typo in that example. The substitution rule $p_3$ should have been
$$A\to\epsilon$$